# Como ejecutar un Update en archivo .bat

Tags: postgresql, batch

Estoy tratando de generar un archivo bat, donde se ingresa a mi base de datos postgres y ejecuta un update referenciado a un SET, adjunto mi sentencia

```
@echo off

set /p OPERACION=¿CUAL ES EL NUMERO DE OPREACION QUE DESEAS HABILITAR RESPUESTA?: 

cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin

psql -p 5432 -h DBA2 -d BaseCrediSolucion -U postgres -w postgres -c "UPDATE tfing11 SET vgret='S' WHERE vgope1=%OPERACION%"
```

Comment: ¿Y cual es el problema? ¿Como ejecutarlo? ¿Te dá un error?. Saludos

Comment: el problema es como ejecutarlo

Comment: Un bat lo ejecutas desde la línea de comandos. Ejecutas un `cmd` y escribes el nombre del archivo `archivo.bat<RETURN>`, no queda claro cual es tu dificultad. Saludos